# Vue mustache not updating inside SVG <text>

Tags: svg, vue.js

Can anyone explain why the text inside `<text>` isn't updating?

https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/LyjdKq?editors=1010

It works when i use `v-html="currentText"` instead of the mustache syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The mustache syntax is not supported by vue ~2.0

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive:

```
<div v-html="rawHtml"></div>
```

> The contents are inserted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored. Note that you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

Comment: yeah but my data IS plain text. that's the problem.